# How can I remove "Some settings are managed by your administrator" in Chrome?

Tags: windows-xp, google-chrome, administrator

I use Google Chrome everywhere : Computers, phone and tablet.

On one computer (the only one running Windows XP), I see a message saying "Some settings are managed by your administrator" in the settings page :

[image: Some settings are managed by your administrator]

What makes Chrome think that an administrator is managing some settings ? In other words, where is that master switch, so I can turn it off ?

Comment: Did you checked [here](https://productforums.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/chrome/TJy1srhiIEQ)?

Comment: Yes, and it leads me to something else. The key is there, but it looks like my account has been denied access to HKCU\Software\Policies\Google\Chrome (confirmed by AccessEnum). I'll post my findings here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A GPO was applied to the computer where Chrome was installed. Nothing fancy other than following [Google's Windows administration quick start for Chrome](http://support.google.com/a/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=187202).

My user account did not have write access to `HKLM\Software\Policies\Google\Chrome`.

The GPO is applied in the registry to `HKLM\Software\Policies\Google\Chrome`. But the Chromium build, the [build you get when you compile Chrome  yourself](http://www.chromium.org/developers/how-tos/build-instructions-windows), follows the policy under `HKLM\Software\Policies\Chromium`.

Switching to Chromium makes the settings available again, but at the cost of loosing the auto-update feature (and the hassle of compiling it).

Answer (score 0):

Because I don't know what policy key to delete, i've erased all the keys under **HKCU\Software\Policies\Google\Chrome** and it worked fine.

(To do a little test I tried to delete key by key and after i've erased **BackgroundModeEnabled**, the message was gone...)